# How do I copy the title of a webpage in Vimperator?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

Is there a shortcut/command to copy the title of a webpage in Vimperator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a key for it built in.

#### Defining a yanktitle command

You can define the following command to do it:

```
:command! yanktitle :js util.copyToClipboard(buffer.title)
```

Or if you prefer, bind a key to the JS command, eg. <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

```
:nmap xy :js util.copyToClipboard(buffer.title)<CR>
```

#### A related command: copy link description

A related command is the extended hint command <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, which copies the description of a link

#### Pentadactyl versions.

```
:command! yanktitle js dactyl.clipboardWrite(buffer.title)
:map -b xy -js dactyl.clipboardWrite(buffer.title)
```